# CakePHP 3 - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and I have recently installed latest version of CakePHP. It works well on my localhost but not working on server. It just shows 500 Internal Error.

I already have CakePHP projects running on my server but only cakephp setups installed and uploaded from Ubuntu are not working on server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what say the logfile ? `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: It seems the problem with `.htaccess`

Comment: what does the PHP  `error_log` say? We need the actual error message

Comment: no errors in error_log and even .htaccess is same as it is on other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing CakePHP3 we are needed to check some configuration in our server.

> Make sure that you have the **mbstring** and **intl** extensions are enabled
>   in PHP.
>        Make sure that you have **pdo_mysql** enabled in PHP.
>   And php version should be 5.6 or greater.
>
> For this go to cpanel and click ***Select php version*** and enable all
>   the required options from the list.

And Xampp
modification :

> Open /xampp/php/php.ini
>       Change ;extension=php_intl.dll to  extension=php_intl.dll (remove the semicolon)

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your suggestions but I already have all these enabled that's why all other projects are working on the same server.

Comment: then check your database configuration

Comment: few days back,I have also faced the same type of problem because of the wrong database configuration

Comment: Using a fresh cakephp setup which works without database configurations. However, it should show database error instead of internal error.
Actually, I have already checked all these possible issues but found no luck.

Comment: Finally, resolved!! There was no problem with the CakePHP and php settings. the issue was with the zip file created from ubuntu system.
I tried to create .tar and uploaded on server it works absolutly fine without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

### You have to enable php-intl extension first

**For Window Users (Xampp Server)**

```
Path :- c:\xampp\php\php.ini 
Uncomment :- 
1. ;extension=php_intl.dll (Remove ;)
2. ;extension=php_mbstring.dll (Remove ;)
```

**For Linux (Open terminal ctr+alt+t)**

```
Run Command :- sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
               sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

***Now Run server*** `bin/cake server`